# SQL Server - Store/save DateDIFF via SQL server agent

Tags: sql-server, datetime, hour

i want to store the fetched difference from the query to the Attendance table via update query. so far I have a table Attendance and DateTime has the Date and time of when the user check-In and i was calculating difference of 'then' datetime with 'now' GetDate(). Time format is 24 hours not 12hours.

```
AttendanceId  UserId  AttendanceStatus Hours CheckIn/Out DateTime
---------------------------------------------------------------------
     1          22         Present       0       In      2016-6-23 5:30:00
     2          23         Present       0       In      2016-6-23 5:30:00
     3          24         Present       0       In      2016-6-23 5:30:00
     4          25         Present       0       In      2016-6-23 5:30:00
```

This the query i used

```
Select [DateTime],
 DATEDIFF(MI, (SELECT IIF(ISDATE([DateTime]) = 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, [DateTime], 111), [DateTime]) as DT_Attendance), GETDATE())/60.0 as Hours_Difference 
from 
Attendance where CheckInCheckOut = 'In' 
and [DateTime] = CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

This is the output i have got:

```
Datetime        Hours_Difference
---------------------------------
2016-6-23          1.20233434
2016-6-23          1.20233434
```

Now, within sql server, i want to update table `Attendance` and store the value '4' in all the rows of column `Hours` where `Hours_Difference = 4 or >4`, respectively, Here (assuming) difference like:

```
    Datetime           Hours_Difference
----------------------------------------
2016-6-23 5:30:00         4.00000000
2016-6-23 5:30:00         5.50323134
```

the final result of table should look like:

```
AttendanceId  UserId  AttendanceStatus Hours CheckIn/Out DateTime
---------------------------------------------------------------------
     1          22         Present       4       In      2016-6-23 5:30:00
     2          23         Present       4       In      2016-6-23 5:30:00
     3          24         Present       4       In      2016-6-23 5:30:00
     4          25         Present       4       In      2016-6-23 5:30:00
```

Comment: I have read this about 6-7 times and it just doesn't make any sense. I have to ask though....why do you have a column named DateTime that isn't a datetime datatype???? You have to check if the value is a valid datetime. That is kind of the point of the datetime datatype, so you don't have to do all this craziness. Would you store integers in varchar? I don't understand why so many people store dates as character data. And really you should avoid reserved words as column names.

Comment: Since you already know `IIF` (which leads to the assumption your tag `mysql` is wrong there), I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for. `IFF (Hours_Difference > 4, round(Hours_Difference,0), Hours_Difference)`?

Comment: @SeanLange Because, i searched the google and there is no help regarding Sql `DateTime` supporting this command used in C# `DateTime like '"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"%'

Comment: @Solarflare bro, i want all rows of `Hours_Difference` and update each row value of `Hours_Difference` on `Attendance` table's `Hours` column with the use of clause `where DateTime`

Comment: So you mean `update attendance set hours = IFF (Hours_Difference > 4, round(Hours_Difference,0), Hours_Difference) where ...`? (Hours_Difference will be your calculation from above)

Comment: Huh??? Your response about C# DateTime doesn't make any sense. You are checking to see if the value is a valid datetime. That is an indication that some value could be invalid. If the datatype is datetime that can't happen. The reason you don't have an answer from anybody yet is that your question is totally unclear. We have no idea what you are trying to get for output.

Comment: @Solarflare, bro, would you join the chat-channel "sql" in stackoverflow, im waiting for you there, please. ^_^

Comment: I'm totally confused; how do you get different results for the same DateTime value `2016-6-23 5:30:00`

Comment: Assuming your `DateTime` values are different actually but a copy paste issue in the question, why a simple `UPDATE` statement doesn't work for you?

Comment: @techspider, DateTime has the Date and time of when the user check-In and i was calculating difference of 'then' datetime with 'now' GetDate().

Yes, you are right that it is a simple update statement, but sometimes we take it over our head and make it complicated. Anyway, I appreciate effort of all of you guys. It is resolved and i insisted that person to post the answer himself here, so i can least mark his answer and mark it 'useful' to give him points. He will post when he'll be back. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussions in chat, the question appears to be

> How can I update the [Hours] column in the [Attendance] table to 4 if the value in the column [DateTime] is 4 hours or more ago, without affecting records before today?

This was complicated, as pointed out by Sean Lange, that the [DateTime] was stored as a string rather than a datetime data type.

This required the `ISDATE` function in the OP's script but eventually the OP found a solution to their liking.

I would agree that the solution is not elegant; the incorrect data type includes lots of possible errors, implied conversions and scalability issues and there is some aspects of it that are redundant, but the OP is quick to mention that they are only using this as a small aspect of a FYP (Final Year Project) with the main aspect being C# and so I wanted to change their script as little as possible to leave it as their own work.

**Quick Modification to the OP's script:**

```
UPDATE
    Attendance 
SET 
    Hours = 4 
WHERE 
    -- The difference in dates in minutes between...
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 

                -- ... DateTime (with a quick data check)...
                (IIF(ISDATE([DateTime]) = 1, 
                CONVERT(DATETIME, [DateTime], 111), 
                [DateTime]))

            -- ... and right now.
            , GetDate()

            -- Divided by 60 to get 
            )/60.0 >= 4 

-- DateTime has to be equal to today (relying on implicit conversion).
and [DateTime] = convert(Date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you for the help by the way ^_^, appreciated!!